# Unique random numbers in PHP

Tags: php, random, numbers, unique

I am trying to display random banners on my page to do this i have a function which gives me a random number and depending on the number i display the banner the problem is that sometimes i get the same number so when the page refreshes the same banner is displayed. I would like to displaye different banner on each page refresh.

Im using the following code to get the random number:

```
function &UniqueRands($min, $max, $keys){
    static $returnme = array();
    while(in_array($x = rand($min,$max),$returnme));
    $returnme[] = $x;
    if($keys < count($returnme)-1 && $keys < ($max-$min))
        UniqueRands($min, $max, $keys);
    return $returnme;
} 

$rands = &UniqueRands(1, 3, 1);
foreach ($rands as $num) {
  echo "$num\n";
}
```

and after i get the random number i just do

```
if ($num=1){
//display banner 1
}
```

...

What I am doing wrong and I would be happy to hear any other ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant `if($num === 1)`

Comment: Suppose you have `N` banners. What happens on the `N+1`th refresh?

Comment: This sounds like a statistical error -- flip a coin three times and there's still a 13% chance you'll end up getting three heads or tails in a row despite it being a 50/50 probability( .5 * .5 * .5 = .125). Try increasing the range for `$min` and `$max`.

Comment: If you refresh the page, it's a new request so a new random number is generated, but previously generated numbers aren't being persisted between requests... and why are you referencing the function with &?

Answer (score 2):

> the problem is that sometimes i get the same number so when the page
>   refreshes the same banner is displayed

Depending on how many banners you have, that is entirely possible. Suppose you have 4 banners, the chances of getting the same two in a row are 1/4.

If you really don't want to the same banner to be displayed twice in a row, you actually need to make it less random rather than more. Store the last banner shown in a cookie or something, then when picking the next banner to show make sure you don't show that one.

Of course, as CanSpice says if you have 4 banners and the user looks at 5 pages then you are going to have to show one banner more than once. But using this method you can stop them seeing the same banner twice in a row at least.

Comment: Apple had exactly the same problem.  http://www.whatdidyoulearntoday.co.uk/post/6692906219/the-ipod-shuffle-feature-was-made-less-random-in-order-t Personally, when it comes to banner ads I'd file this under "really not important" and move on.

Comment: Assume 4 banners: chances of getting no.1 twice is (1/4)x(1/4), chances of getting no.2 twice is (1/4)x(1/4), etc, so chances of getting any banner twice in a row is (1/4)x(1/4)+(1/4)x(1/4)+(1/4)x(1/4)+(1/4)x(1/4) or 1/4.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP are you using? Since 4.2 `rand()` function is seeded automatically, but if you are using older one, you have to use `srand()` function before calling `rand()` function to initialize random number generator. Or maybe `mt_rand()` will help.

Answer (score 0):

mt_rand[1] supposedly produces better ("more random") pseudo-random numbers, compare [2]

[1] http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

[2] http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/